# I want to merge image audio and subtitle with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to merge image audio and subtitle with ffmpeg, but what i do doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i 1.png -vcodec libx264 -r 23.976 -vf "ass='subtitle.ass'" -acodec copy video.mp4
```

I can see the image and hear the music, but not the subtitle.  Here is the console output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)   configuration: --prefix=/usr
--extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
--enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libpulse --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr1 --disable-mipsdspr2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libzvbi --enable-avresample --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --enable-libutvideo --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx265 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-vaapi --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu   libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100   libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100   libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101   libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100   libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102   libavresample   2.  1.  0 / 
2.  1.  0   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100 [mjpeg @ 0x1802f00] Changeing bps to 8 Input #0, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':   Metadata:
    album           : もしもからきっと
    artist          : 東條希(CV.楠田亜衣奈)
    genre           : Anime
    title           : もしもからきっと
    track           : 1/2
    date            : 2014   Duration: 00:05:18.90, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 322 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 300x376, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : 
      comment         : Cover (front) Input #1, png_pipe, from '1.png':   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24, 668x376 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 167:94], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc [Parsed_ass_0 @ 0x17cb6c0] Added subtitle file: 'subtitle.ass' (2 styles, 11 events) No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen. Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players. [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] using SAR=1/1 [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.0, 4:4:4 8-bit [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] 264 - core 146 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':   Metadata:
    album           : もしもからきっと
    artist          : 東條希(CV.楠田亜衣奈)
    genre           : Anime
    title           : もしもからきっと
    track           : 1/2
    date            : 2014
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 668x376 [SAR 1:1 DAR 167:94], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 11988 tbn,
23.98 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, stereo, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r Stream mapping:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=28.0 Lsize=   12524kB time=00:05:18.87 bitrate= 321.7kbits/s     video:17kB audio:12457kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.394340% [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] frame I:1     Avg QP:31.93  size: 17171 [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] mb I  I16..4:  1.2% 77.3% 21.5% [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] 8x8 transform intra:77.3% [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] coded y,u,v intra: 41.5% 25.9% 25.0% [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 58% 25% 17%  0% [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 39%  8% 38%  2%  2%  3%  2%  3%  3% [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 18% 12%  7%  9%  8%  9%  7%  7% [libx264 @ 0x180f9a0] kb/s:3293.54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -loop 1 -i 1.png -c:v libx264 -r 24000/1001 -vf "ass='subtitle.ass'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -map 1:v -map 0:a -shortest video.mp4
```

FFmpeg typically works with timed media sequences i.e. video or audio or image seqeunces. When fed a single image, it treats it as one frame of duration `1/fps` where fps is typically 25. So, there's no video canvas on which to draw the subtitles. Adding the input loop option to the image tells FFmpeg to generate an indefinite video stream out of it.